# Compare means of two datasets of binary data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I need to compare means of two data sets that binary. For example:

```
a = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
```

All I need to know is whether the means are statistically significantly different between the two datasets, in other words the order in which `1` are arranged does not matter. And I do know that all values are either `0` or `1`. Also in my case sizes of and be are fairly large, greater than `10,000` and number of `1` is about `10` to `100`.

What is the best test to use in this case?

I know that I cannot use `t-test` because my data is not normally distributed.

Comment: Means of 0-1 variables are the same thing as "the proportion of 1's" (both in sample and population senses). That is, you're in the situation of comparing proportions. *If* the variables satisfy the conditions of bernoulli trials (independence, homogeneity of probability of 1's), then a two-sample proportions test (or a chi-square, or several other tests suitable for such tables) would be the obvious analyses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can express your data in the form of a [contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).
For a small N you can use [Fisher's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) to test whether your measurements a and b are dependent on each other.

For a larger N you can use the [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)

Comment: Thank You. I think Fisher exact test is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a similar (non-parametric) test of binary datasets where each dataset has a different number of samples?

Comment: I've answered my question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25299/comparing-two-binary-variables-of-unequal-sizes

Though, I can't find a more general test for discrete variables

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case means and proportions are the same 
you can use proportions test for testing the null that 
the proportions (probabilities of success) in groups 
are the same.

As for reference I can suggest the
Hollander and Wolfe's book Nonparametric Statistical Methods